# vuejs loop through items, every 3 items new row

Tags: vue.js

Currently i have this code, which shows 3 items in each row.

```
<b-container class="tags">
<b-row v-for="index in 3" :key="index">
   <b-col>
      <MovieItem />
   </b-col>
   <b-col>
      <MovieItem />
   </b-col>
   <b-col>
      <MovieItem />
   </b-col>
</b-row>
</b-container>
```

Now i have returned results from api and i want in the same format as above.  I know how to loop through results but how do i add wrap the code in `b-col` and `b-row` so it is same format as above?

```
<b-container class="tags">
    <MovieItem  v-for="(movie,index) in MovieItems" :key="index" />
</b-container>
```

How do i solve?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the length of `MovieItems`, you can calculate how many rows are needed with `Math.floor((MovieItems.length - 1) / 3) + 1`:

```
computed: {
  nrows() {
    return Math.floor((MovieItems.length - 1) / 3) + 1;
  }
}
```

In your template, use a nested loop assuming `MovieItem` component takes `movie` as a prop:

```
<b-row v-for="row in nrows" :key="row">
   <b-col v-for="col in 3" :key="col">
      <MovieItem :movie="MovieItems[row * 3 + col] v-if="row * 3 + col < MovieItems.length" />
   </b-col>
</b-row>
```

Comment: The "MovieItems[row * 3 + col]" is not correct, I think it should be " MovieItems[col + 3 * (row - 1) - 1]", and you are missing a double quote before the v-if.